# Reviwing in beta

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I have a new problem with the site...

When I go into the site,the black bar at the top of the page shows me that I have for example 5 posts to review,but when I click on it,And it goes to the review page,there is nothing to review.

As I said,I didn't have this problem before and It doesn't change by refreshing the page.

what is the reason of it?and what is the solution?

Comment: It's a known issue (the count is not personalized) and as I understand is not planned to be fixed anytime soon so you should just get used to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design.  The Review notification shows you the number of pending reviews for the *site*, not the number of reviews that you, personally, can take action on.  Chances are, those five posts were ones that you have already personally cast your own vote on, but they're still waiting for votes from other users before they can actually be removed from the queue.

If this number isn't going down on its own despite you clearing your own personal Review queue regularly, that typically just means that the other users on the site aren't pulling their weight.

See also this relevant MSE post: [Notification for reviews shows way too much](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230742/132874)